# Filepath issue with Sharepoint in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hope everyone could help me with this. My workplace has moved everything to Sharepoint and one of the file that was created by our former Business Analyst stopped working. The part where it stops working is it could not access the file and giving me this error
[image]
I checked and made sure that the file is in there. But for some reason it keeps giving me this error, check with IT, there is no access issues, no one has it open as it is a test file that I created.

Through what I found on google, it seems that if I could find a way to convert the file path to \filepath\folder\file.ext as opposed to http://filepath/folder/file.ext it might work, however, the methods that I found are no longer there and I cannot use the file path in file explorer where it includes my username, as this file is used by 3 persons. Does anyone have a solution for this ?

I have tried using the URL to access a file and it keeps giving me the 1004 runtime error as above